# How to export part of a table as SQL in Adminer?

Tags: php, mysql, database, export, adminer

In Adminer, I can export whole tables with the "Export" menu option. When I enter a query, I can export the results as .CSV or .TSV, but not as SQL.

Is there any option to do so? A plugin or a config switch?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to export the data as a bunch of inserts?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am aiming for.

Comment: Never actualy used Adminer, but you can also convert the csv to sql query with http://www.convertcsvtomysql.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adminer doesn't offer SQL export of a general SQL query because the query may join more tables which would be impossible to export to SQL.

To export a subset of rows in a single table, go to the Select view of this table, filter the results as you wish and check the rows you want to export (or check 'whole result' to export all rows in the result). Then use the Export button under the table.

Answer (score 4):

In current version it is possible with Search

1. Select column
2. Select **SQL** as mark
3. Into value field fill subquery **IN (SELECT id FROM ...)**

Answer (score 1):

if you click on export then on that page see there is a radio button named `dump`. put no of rows you wanted to pick up and starting record index number. then you will get your expected result

Comment: Sorry @ripa, but I can't find this option. I checked in Adminer 3.6.1 and Adminer 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this:

1. Go to `Adminer`-> Click on `Dump` in top left side.
2. `Output`-> check `save` radio button
3. `Format`-> check `SQL` radio button
4. Go to below `Export` button
5. Mark checkboxes of `Tables` (if you want to data then mark checked `Data`)
6. If you want 1 table then mark one checkbox of a table.
7. Click on `Export` button.

Here we go :), Coool ;)